# subtract List by objid

Tags: groovy

I have this code in `Groovy`:

```
def list1 = [[objid:1, name:"One"], [objid:2, name:"Two"]];
def list2 = [[objid:2, name:"Hello"]];
def list3 = list1 - list2;

println list3;
```

The output of the code above will result something like this:

```
[[objid:1, name:One], [objid:2, name:Two]]
```

**QUESTION:** How to subtract `List` by objid? I want the result to be something like this: `[[objid:1, name:One]]` since `objid:2` is present in the `List1`. How to code it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given

```
list1 = [[objid:1, name:"One"], [objid:2, name:"Two"]]
list2 = [[objid:2, name:"Hello"]]
```

In order to get list1 entries with entries matching objids from list2 filtered out, collect the ids that need to be subtracted into a set, then construct a predicate that tests that the id of the given object isn't in that set:

```
ids = list2.collect { it['objid'] } as Set
list3 = list1.findAll { !ids.contains(it['objid']) }
```

(Using a set instead of a list should make the lookups faster.)

The result is that list3 contains:

```
[[objid:1, name:One]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You may need a function, try this:

```
def list1 = [[objid:1, name:"One"], [objid:2, name:"Two"]];
def list2 = [[objid:2, name:"Hello"]];

​​def subtract (list1, list2) {
    def retlist = [];
    if (list1 == null || list2 == null) {
        return null;
    }

    for(test1 in list1) {
        def exists = false;
        for (test2 in list2) {
            exists = (test1.objid == test2.objid) || exists;
        }
        if (!exists) {
            retlist.push(test1);
        }
    }
    return retlist;
}

def list3 = subtract(list1 ,list2)​​;

println list3;​
```

Comment: Oh men! The code was too long! So, there are no groovy facility for this?

Comment: Thanks to @gotnull.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want a function that does the following:

```
class Foo
{
    public String Name;
    public Integer Id;
}

public Foo getObjId(int id) {
    for (Foo foo : list) {
      if (foo.getId() == id) {
        return foo; // foo bar!
      }
    }
    return null; // foo bar not found.
}
```